# Adding an erase feature to a CGContext application

Tags: cocoa-touch, cgcontext

I am an amateur developer for iPhones and I have developed an application that uses CGContext to draw images on the screen. I have one problem though, erasing the image. Please can I have help to add an erase feature to my application, like I said I am very inexperienced and it would be helpful if someone can give me step by step instructions on how to add an erase feature, including the code for .h or .m files and if i need to link anything up in the .xib file.

P.S The erase feature i would like is a simple gesture (double tap) to erase the whole screen, even a round rect button would do fine.

Thank You very much in advance!

Comment: So when you say "draw" you are obviously storing the user's "brush strokes" in a some collection and then drawing them as required, or are you drawing directly into the frame buffer (yuck)?

Answer (score 0):

Erasing in a CGContext is the sane as drawing. 
Just draw whatever color you want to be the erased area, the setNeedsDisplay or other method to make the view redraw itself.